# How to build personal name server

Tags: dns, nameservers

I've purchased a domain from one of the domain registrar company and now don't want to use nameserver provided by them. I'm hosting the website on my local machine and want entire setup to be private (except for domain registration). How this can be achieved? Please be advised this is only for educational purpose and better understanding of how DNS works. In my understand I'll need the following:

1. A nameserver, which will have an A record for the host where website
   resides.
2. A DNS server with NS record, here I'm confused as what
       should I fill in for NS record?

Please advise.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "private"? As in you don't want your domain/website to be accessible on the public Internet?

Comment: What I meant by private was, self built. I’ve edited it now since it seemed to be misleading.

Comment: In general, it's pretty difficult to host a website on your local machine. This is because usually your public IP address is assigned via DHCP from your ISP (meaning it changes often). There are ways around this, but it can be a pain. I think it's great that you want to learn though.

Comment: If you really want to host your own authoritative DNS you may want to look into ISC BIND. Its one of the more popular DNS servers out there. As @kimbo mentioned, if you are doing this at home then you may also need to periodically check your IP and if it has changed update your host records at your BIND server and the glue records at your registrar for you name servers. Though it would be pretty trivial for you to do this on a VM on AWS or something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks @Ivrf and kimbo,